# Creating buttons in Java with custom font causes buttons to have strange shape

Tags: java, css, button, javafx, fonts

I've been trying to create javafx buttons with a custom font. The font is in the resources directory of my project and applied to the buttons via a css stylesheet. The problem is that the buttons become really tall. As soon as I remove the css line that changes the font, the buttons look just as usual. The buttons themselves are inside a HBox which is in the bottom region of a BorderPane. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? Manually changing the dimension doesn't help.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MODERNA';
    src: url('/fonts/MODERNA_.ttf');
}

.label {
    -fx-font-family: 'MODERNA';
    -fx-font-size: 20;
}

.button .text {
    -fx-font-family: 'MODERNA';
}

.button {
    -fx-background-color: #F5E050;
    -fx-pref-height: 30px;
    -fx-pref-width: 100px;
}
```

[strange, disproportioned buttons with custom font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZ2HM.png)
[normal looking buttons with standard font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ut4oq.png)

Comment: Does setting the `maxHeight` of the `Button` change it?

Comment: @Zephyr maxHeight does not change anything, no.

Comment: I've now switched over to try and work with scenebuilder but the problem persists

Comment: You'll need to provide a [mcve] for us to really figure out what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and wanted to let anyone having the same problem know.
@Zephyr wasn't far off, however it was maxHeight but minHeight that created the problem. It has to be set to USE_PREF_SIZE in the SceneBuilder instead of USE_COMPUTED_SIZE wich seems to be the default value. After that simply change you prefSize in SceneBuilder's UI and everything works out great. The problem must have been the system failing to calculate the correct height on its own, for whatever reason, proably something to do with the font, because it didn't happen with any other fonts.